# If and Multiple Statement

Tags: simulink

I am very new to Simulink.

I want to achieve the following:

```
if(U1 > U2)
{
   E = U1 + U2
   D = U1 * A
}
else if(U1 < U2)
{
   E = U1 - U2
   D = U1 * B
}
else
{
   E = U1
   D = U2 * U2
}
```

Could you please help me how to represent the above in Simulink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could implement this.

One is to use an [If](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/if.html) subsystem.  On the left of the image below is the high level of the implementation.  On the right are the contents of the `If`, `ElseIf` and `Else` subsystems.  You probably also want to look at the doc for the [Merge](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/merge.html) block to see how it *selects* which signal is passed through to be the final value for `D` and `E`.

[image: If Action model]

Another would be to use a [MATLAB Function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block,

[image]

Comment: Thanks...Modified as per your suggesstion